# Bamboo - Correct format of SCP call in an SSH task

Tags: ssh, scp, bamboo

I'm using Bamboo OnDemand and am trying to setup an SSH task to copy files.  (NB: The SCP standalone task is not currently an option).

Whatever I try as the ssh command results in the error..

```
invalid characters in scp command!
```

I've researched the message and it typically relates to file or directory names with reserved characters e.g. space but I don't have any of those. Testing it with just a simple file (index.php) fails.

The commands I have tried are:

```
scp index.php user@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test
scp index.php 'user@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test'
scp index.php "user@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test"
scp "index.php" "user@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test"
"scp index.php user@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test"
scp index.php user@mydomain.co.uk://httpdocs//test
scp index.php user@mydomain.co.uk:\/httpdocs\/test
scp index.php user@mydomain.co.uk:"//httpdocs//test"
```

all result in the same error...

`simple 29-Oct-2014 09:06:11    Starting task 'SSH Test' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-scp-plugin:sshtask'
simple  29-Oct-2014 09:06:12    Connecting to mydomain.co.uk on port: 22
simple  29-Oct-2014 09:06:13    Executing [scp index.php user@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test]
error   29-Oct-2014 09:06:13    invalid characters in scp command!
error   29-Oct-2014 09:06:13    here:@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test
error   29-Oct-2014 09:06:13    try using a wildcard to match this file/directory
simple  29-Oct-2014 09:06:13    [scp index.php user@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test] has finished.
error   29-Oct-2014 09:06:13    Result: exit code = 1`

could anyone share a valid example of an scp command via an ssh task? Or is this not actually possible and you're forced to use the SCP dedicated task? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"invalid characters in scp command!...try using a wildcard to match this file/directory" is an error emitted by the `scponly` program. Scponly is used as a shell for users who are only permitted to do scp transfers in or out of a host. The immediate cause of the error is that you're trying to run the command "scp index.php user@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test" on mydmain.co.uk, which isn't permitted by the scponly program.

I think the real issue here is that you're using ssh and scp incorrectly. You're using ssh to connect to mydomain.co.uk, then trying to run the command "scp index.php user@mydomain.co.uk:/httpdocs/test" on that host. This means you're running scp on mydomain.co.uk, copying index.php from mydomain.co.uk to mydomain.co.uk.

I presume what you really want to do is to run `scp` on your *local* host, copying the file to mydomain.co.uk. I don't know exactly what capabilities Bamboo has, but you wouldn't use an ssh task for this. You'd want to use a task which runs commands on the *local* host, not on some remote host.

Comment: You can use a script task for this, but you need to make sure that the `ssh` command is working properly, which depends on the configuration of your build agent (it might not be in `%PATH%`/`$PATH`)